# What's the right adjective to describe a joke that is not the greatest?

Tags: word-choice

What's the right adjective to describe a joke that is not the greatest, that is, not as funny as other jokes are?

For example:

> Usually, Jack reacts with a lot of laughter even to **the smallest**
>   of my jokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Usually, Jack reacts with a lot of laughter even to the smallest of my jokes.

Keeping your sentence as close as possible:
**Usually, Jack reacts with laughter even at the least of my jokes.**

*React to* is grammatically correct in your sentence, but *laugh at* would sound more natural. If I were to say it myself:
**Usually, Jack laughs at even my worst jokes.**

*Least* and *worst* both indicate the joke is not very clever, but the attempt at humor is understood.

A "bad" joke is not funny at all, and would not be funny even if said by a comedian.

A "little" joke is cautious or gentle, perhaps the listener is not in the mood to laugh or the situation is not appropriate.

When a joke is "small" there is a hint that it was not actually intended as a joke, but something mean or cruel said in the form of a joke. This is similar to "small minded". The joke may be racist or at someone else's expense.

A "big joke" is also a negative, meaning over-inflated or never taken seriously: "He acted like our wedding was just a big joke!"

Comment: Thank you. Is it okay to say "with a lot of laughter" (I noticed, you've dropped "a lot of" in your answer) or "with much laughter" in case Jack is a bit abnormal and, unlike others, laughs too loud and too much?

Comment: Maybe *"laughs too loud"* or *"laughs loudly"*… The awkward part is "reacts with laughter". The meaning is clear, but laughter is already a reaction so it feels stiff or strangely formal, like too many words.

Comment: +1. **dumbest** is also an idiomatic possibility there, alongside **worst**.